# Collapse only a subset of the dataset with "if"

Tags: stata

I'm trying to `collapse` only a subset of my data using `if`, but it seems to be dropping / collapsing much more than I expect.

With every other command with which I have used an `if` qualifier, the command applies only to the subset of the data that meets the `if` criteria and *leaves the rest of the data alone*.

For example, `replace` does not alter the data for which `foreign != 1`:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. replace mpg = 16 if foreign == 1
(22 real changes made)
```

However, it appears that `collapse` applies to the data that meets the `if` criteria and *drops the rest*:

```
. count if mpg > -1
  74

. * all the data has mpg > -1

. count if foreign == 1
  22

. collapse (mean) mpg if foreign == 1

. count if mpg > -1
  1
```

There is no reason why `collapse` could not in theory work the same way as `replace`. It could leave all the `foreign != 1` intact, while collapsing all `foreign == 1` data to one observation.

That is in fact what I want to do with my data, so what should I do differently?

@NickCox helpfully suggested something like this:

```
. save "temp/whatever"
file temp/whatever.dta saved

. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. drop if foreign == 1
(22 observations deleted)

. append using "temp/whatever"
(note: variable mpg was int, now float to accommodate using data's values)
```

That works in this sandbox, but my dataset has 10 million observations. If I can avoid having to re-load it, I can save myself a half hour. More if I have to do this for multiple cases.

Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help and guidance in improving this question! I am not a stackoverflow etiquette expert either and learned several things about using the platform (eg when to put something in comments vs the question, when to edit the question in response to expert suggestions) that I will do differently in the future.

Comment: @RGecon we now have a question for this: [How to ask high quality reproducible questions in Stata](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377015/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collapse` with `if` works this way:

Those observations selected by the `if` condition are `collapse`d, typically (but not necessarily) into a new dataset with fewer observations.

Those observations not selected disappear.

It's incorrect to say that this command is unusual, let alone unique, in that respect. `contract` and `keep` also work in this way: whatever is not selected disappears. 
(The community has often asked for `save` with `if`: `savesome` from SSC is one work-around.)

If you want to `collapse` some of the observations but leave the others unchanged, then you can try

A. this strategy

A1. `use` your dataset

A2. `keep if` what you want unchanged and `save` those observations

A3. `use` your dataset again

A4. `collapse` to taste

A5. `append` the dataset from A2

```
sysuse auto, clear
keep if !foreign 
save domestic 
sysuse auto, clear
collapse mpg if foreign 
gen make = "All foreign" 
append using domestic
```

or B. this one:

B1. work with (if needed create) an identifier that is unique (distinct) for the observations you want unchanged but takes on a single value for the observations you want `collapse`d

B2. `collapse` feeding that identifier to `by()`.

```
sysuse auto, clear 
replace make = "All foreign" if foreign 
collapse mpg, by(make)
```

Although B looks trivial for this example, it is far from obvious to me that it is always superior for large datasets and if you want to continue to work with many variables. I have not experimented with timing or memory comparisons for large datasets or even any datasets, as I haven't encountered this wish before.